# Reading an operator preset, the right way?

Tags: python, operator

What I'm trying to do: import a bunch of fbx files with consistent (non-default) importer settings, that looks like this:

- user invokes the importer to bring up its UI;
- user sets desired values in the UI, and saves them as a named preset;
- user runs a script with directory path, and the preset name as input;
- the script reads the preset once, and then calls importer many times
  with the same settings to import all needed files from the given directory;

As I see the preset system seems to be intended to be used in the UI only. The only place I found in python files, is **presets.py** with its **ExecutePreset** class.
To execute the **"script.execute_preset"** operator I need to open UI, get the window context, etc. It looks a bit crutchy and unreliable.
Finally, I ended up with 'manual approach':

```
def get_presets_dir(operator_bl_idname):
    " returns presets directory path for the given operator. "
    return os.path.join(bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS'),
                        os.path.normpath(r"presets/operator/"),
                        operator_bl_idname)
    
def read_operator_preset(operator_bl_idname, preset_name, ignore_keys=()):
    " returns a dict with given preset values."
    # find the preset if given
    preset_path = os.path.join(get_presets_dir(operator_bl_idname), preset_name + ".py")
    if os.path.isfile(preset_path):
        # prepare the file content for execution, removing lines not containing setters ("op.xxx = ")
        with open(preset_path, "r") as f:
            text = "".join([s for s in f.readlines() if s.startswith('op.')])
        # execute the script to collect values
        op = SimpleNamespace()
        exec(text)
        return {k : v for k, v in op.__dict__.items() if k not in ignore_keys}
    else:
        return {}

# reading it once
preset_dict = read_operator_preset("import_scene.fbx", fbx_import_preset_name, ("directory", "filepath",))

fbx_filenames = [fname for fname in os.listdir(src_dir) if fname.lower().endswith(".fbx")]
for file_name in fbx_filenames:
    fbx_path = os.path.join(src_dir, file_name)
    # applying many times
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_path, **preset_dict)
```

It also looks like a crutch, and it may break in many ways, but I think it at least will work regardless of the UI (even in a headless session). So, the question is: is there **a right way** to read a preset not from its operator, but from outside? Is there any API for this?

Using Blender v2.76b; PC; Windows;